# Does XSLT 1.0 support intermediate results?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, foreach, return

TL;DR: How can I represent an `<apply-templates />` statement with XPath?

---

I've got a template that collates information. I'd like to further process this information in more than one different way, so I was wondering whether there was a way to sort of "return" from a template in XSLT.

Example: I've got an XHTML snippet:

```
<page html:xmlns="html namespace">
  <html:p>
    The <html:a href="/foo">Tropical Foo</html:a> uses <html:a href="bar-language">Bar</html:a> to implement <html:a href="/programs/fizzbuzz>FizzBuzz</html:a>
  </html:p>
</page>
```

I've got a template to extract `<a>` tags with an `href` from an HTML snippet. I'd like to reuse this twice to both prefetch the pages *and* add a "Linked" bar, like so:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="prefetch" href="/foo" />
    <link rel="prefetch" href="bar-language" />
    <link rel="prefetch" href="/programs/fizzbuzz" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <p>
        The <a href="/foo">Tropical Foo</a> uses <a href="bar-language">Bar</a> to implement <a href="/programs/fizzbuzz>FizzBuzz</a>
      </p>
    </main>
    <aside>
      <h2>Linked</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/foo">Tropical Foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="bar-language">Bar</a></li>
        <li><a href="/programs/fizzbuzz>FizzBuzz</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this possible in XSLT 1.0?

---

If it's easier, I've got a related variant of the problem where I'm transforming an entire document with a stylesheet, and then want to use the transformed version. I know I can `<xsl:include>` the other-document-transforming stylesheet and write `<xsl:apply-templates select="document('other.xml')"/>`, but I want to further transform the result of this.

Comment: So how does that template you have "to extract `<a>` tags with an href from an HTML snippet` look exactly, what does it return? In what way do you expect to be able to use an intermediary result twice? And of course, given XSLT 1, do you expect to process intermediary results in forms of nodes further with or without the use of an extension function like `exsl:node-set`? You can certainly push the same XPath selection (e.g. `//xhtml:a[@href]`) to different templates using modes to transform the same input nodes two or more times to different output.

Comment: @MartinHonnen The template is literally `<xsl:copy-of select="html:a[@href]" />` but I'd like this to work for more complicated examples.

Comment: That doesn't make sense then, the input has some not really spelled out namespace, the result you show doesn't have any namespace. So a simply `xsl:copy-of` would never work to process input in certain namespace to get a result in no namespace. And of course, on the other hand, if all you want is select input nodes then you don't need a template use a variable `<xsl:variable name="links" select="html:a[@href]"/>`, then push the variable to different templates with different modes to construct the different presentations.

Comment: @MartinHonnen That `xsl:variable` definition works perfectly for an XPath expression, but what if I wanted to define the XPath expression somewhere else? And what if I wanted to have something more complicated than simply an XPath expression?

Comment: I don't think we can and should rewrite tutorials on XSLT here, see for instance the book https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm in chapter 3 XPath data model explaining the restrictions of XSLT 1 with "one cannot push or pull nodes of a result tree fragment". But as I already indicated, there are extension functions like `exsl:node-set` to convert a result tree fragment to a node-set. So with a certain XSLT 1.0 processor you can usually use such a function.

Comment: If you target various, like in the browser, it is more difficult as Microsoft has its own proprietary namespace and function, so to write cross processor code you might need to check with `function-available` or you need Javascript based extension hacks to have IE or Edge map its Microsoft extension function to the EXSLT one.

Comment: @MartinHonnen That sounds like "No, but it's possible in `exsl`" which would be a valid answer. (Button below!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 adds one data type to the four (string, number, boolean, node-set) incorporated from the data model of XPath 1.0: result tree fragments (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Result-Tree-Fragments):

> This additional data type is called result tree fragment. A variable
>   may be bound to a result tree fragment instead of one of the four
>   basic XPath data-types (string, number, boolean, node-set). A result
>   tree fragment represents a fragment of the result tree. A result tree
>   fragment is treated equivalently to a node-set that contains just a
>   single root node. However, the operations permitted on a result tree
>   fragment are a subset of those permitted on a node-set. An operation
>   is permitted on a result tree fragment only if that operation would be
>   permitted on a string (the operation on the string may involve first
>   converting the string to a number or boolean). In particular, it is
>   not permitted to use the `/`, `//`, and `[]` operators on result tree
>   fragments.

So you can have intermediary results as result tree fragments but if you expect to use anything more than `xsl:copy-of` or `xsl:value-of` or taking the string value you need to go beyond XSLT 1.0 and in most XSLT 1.0 processors you have support for an extension function like `exsl:node-set` to do that, it converts a result tree fragment to a node-set.

Here is a simple example that first processes some elements from an input to add an attribute and converts that result tree fragment into a node-set using `exsl:node-set` (http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) to then use that node-set twice for two different modes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl msxml"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

  <xsl:variable name="numbered-items-rtf">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//item" mode="number"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="numbered-items" select="exsl:node-set($numbered-items-rtf)/item"/>

  <xsl:template match="item" mode="number">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="index">
              <xsl:number/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
        <style>
            nav ul li { display: inline }
            nav ul { list-item-type: none }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
          <h1>Example</h1>
          <nav>
              <ul>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="$numbered-items" mode="nav"/>
              </ul>
          </nav>
          <section>
              <h2>List</h2>
              <ul>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="$numbered-items"/>
              </ul>
          </section>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
      <li id="item-{@index}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item" mode="nav">
      <li>
          <a href="#item-{@index}">
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </a>
      </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A sample input like

```
<root>
    <items>
        <item>foo</item>
        <item>bar</item>
        <item>baz</item>
    </items>
</root>
```

is transformed to

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-doctype">
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16">
    <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
    <style>
            nav ul li { display: inline }
            nav ul { list-item-type: none }
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1><nav><ul>
        <li><a href="#item-1">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item-2">bar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item-3">baz</a></li>
      </ul></nav><section><h2>List</h2>
      <ul>
        <li id="item-1">foo</li>
        <li id="item-2">bar</li>
        <li id="item-3">baz</li>
      </ul></section></body>
</html>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUd/1

The draw back is that some XSLT 1.0 processors don't support the `exsl:node-set` function but a similar in a proprietary namespace (for instance Microsoft's COM based MSXML (3,4,5,6) processors only support `msxml:node-set` in the namespace `xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"`, like does the (obsolete) .NET based `XslTransform`). As long as you target a single XSLT 1.0 processor you can of course adapt your code to use the right namespace/extension function but if you want to target different ones you will struggle to find a compact and elegant way to use different extension functions based on `function-available` as you don't have an `if` expression in XPath 1.0.

So https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUd/2 works with e.g. Chrome and with Mozilla browsers like Firefox as these browsers do support `exsl:node-set` but fails in Microsoft IE and Edge as these use MSXML and don't support `exsl:node-set`, for them you need `<xsl:variable name="numbered-items" select="msxml:node-set($numbered-items-rtf)/item"/>` as done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUd/3.

In IE you can use a script extension to have it support `exsl:node-set` but unfortunately in Edge this doesn't work: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7598626/.