# How to select elements from an xml variable in xslt-1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have here an xslt transform, including this:

```
<xsl:variable name="mydict">
  <dict>
    <entry name="a" value="1"/>
    <entry name="b" value="2"/>
    <entry name="c" value="3"/>
    <entry name="d" value="4"/>
  </dict>
</xsl:variable>
```

That works, I can refer it as `$mydict` and, for example, print it with an `<xsl:copy-of select="$mydict"/>`.

However, things are becoming ugly from the moment if I want to actually use it for something, more clearly if I want to use it as a dictionary. Or map. Or string-indexed string-array.

How can I get, for example, `3` if I have another variable with value `"c"`?

My tries with `$mydict//entry[@name="$c"]` and similars all failed with various symptoms. I think, problem might root in that `$mydict` is like a string and not a node, in which I could do various operations (most importantly, refering its parts by xpath queries).

I have here an `xsltproc` command line tool and I would be happy to remain by it, but a switch to the latest saxon is possible if there is no better way.

Comment: I could export the `<dict>` into an external document and then refer it with `document('dict.xml')` but I do not want to do that. I want to query the variable, not an external document.

Comment: 1) I am happy to accept a better answer as my self-answer. 2) Closure as dupe would be okay, but note: I could not find a content saying exactly what I wanted by google.

Comment: Searching for "XSLT result tree fragment" would have found the answer - but then you would have to know that what you're dealing with is called a result tree fragment. For further background see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023985/whats-the-rationale-behind-result-tree-fragments

Comment: In XSLT 1.0, without a `node-set()` extension you can use `<xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='mydict']/dict/entry[@name='d']/@value"/>`. Alternatively, with `key()` and data islands in the stylesheet, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68578384).

Comment: @urznow Thank you the beautiful solution! If you convert it to an answer in a week, I will give it an upvote and an accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented your variable holds a *result tree fragment*
([RTF](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#dt-result-tree-fragment)), not a node set.

In XSLT 1.0, without a [`node-set()`](https://exslt.github.io/exsl/) extension, the
[`document`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-document) function can access the RTF
due to the fact that XSL is also XML, e.g.

```xml
<xsl:variable name="de" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='mydict']/dict/entry"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$de[@name='c']/@value"/>
```

Alternatively, data islands in the stylesheet can be used with
`key()`, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68578384).

Comment: However, more often than not the RTF is *created* by the stylesheet, not *embedded* in it - and in such case the `document()` function cannot help.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Indeed, hence the bad rep RTF got.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found the solution. The `node-set` function does it an then a

```
<xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($mydict)//dict/type[@name='$idx']"/>
```

will do what I want. The important things are:

1. `node-set($mydict)` can convert `$mydict` from an xml variable to an actual node. As a node-set, it can also have more than one top-level node.
2. `node-set()` is not part of the basic xslt, but it is an extension. Fortunately, this extension is supported by xsltproc, but it requires a declaration in its `<xml` namespace header, roughly so:

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet
       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
       xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
     >
   ```

After that, we have our `node-set()` method as `exsl:node-set`.

Comment: Indeed, your variable as defined is a [result tree fragment](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#section-Result-Tree-Fragments) - a data-type unique to XSLT 1.0. Practically all XSLT 1.0 processors support some type of a `node-set()` extension function to deal with this unfortunate creation of XSLT 1.0. It was abandoned in later versions, even in XSLT  1.1.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Ahh thanks! I think exactly this is what we need: a lot of useful xslt and any hardcore xml content, to help google to find the best.

Comment: Note also that, with XSLT 2 and later, there are no longer any result tree fragments, instead, your variable holds an intermediary tree on which you can apply XPath as on any normal input tree, i.e. you don't need any node-set function to convert anything. So with a modern XSLT processor (the latest version is XSLT 3 from 2017) this problem does not arise.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks! Two questions: 1) what is the root element of such a tree 2) how the xslt processor decides that I wanted to give him a node tree, and not its string representation?

Comment: Please read https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#temporary-trees or more generally https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#variables-and-parameters. A tree doesn't even need to have a root element (it can just be a root/document node containing text, comments, pis, for instance) so I am not sure what you are asking about with the root element. The second question doesn't even make any sense to me, you would need to use `<xsl:variable name="xml-string" as="xs:string"><![CDATA[<foo>bar</foo>]]></xsl:variable>` if you expect to bind a variable to a string of XML markup and to to a tree.

Comment: The final part of the last comment is supposed to say "and not to a tree".

Comment: @MartinHonnen Ahh okay thanks. But an xml document, that must have a single root element, or not? My experiences with xml documents with multiple top-level tags, well they looked well for me, but never for my tools.

Comment: In the definition of a well-formed XML document in the XML specification, yes, but there are other uses cases like a DOM document fragment or an external parsed entity. And in XSLT/XPath (and XQuery) a document node can represent an XML document but also a document fragment or external parsed entity.

Comment: As for tools, in the .NET world at least, both XmlReader as well as XPathDocument can consume input with "conformance level fragment" where you could have multiple top level elements or none at all. And of course any XML parser allowing external entities (https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#wf-entities) will at least internally have some way to parse them, it might not necessarily exposed as a public API, however.